# PCL vs .NET Standard library for SQLite in UWP

Tags: sqlite, uwp, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I have following problem.

I use Portable library in my UWP application (Portable library is shared with Xamarin app). This portable library references SQLite. In this Portable library I also use Prism and Unity. For that reason I still can't upgrade them to .NET Standard. SQLite library I use is SQLite-net-pcl version 1.4.18.

In my UWP app I add same nugget package. The problem is that this nugget package also support .net standard, as result, when I build my UWP library, I got different version of SQLite-net.dll, from netstandard1.1.

And as result of this, when I run application I got an exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'SQLite-net, Version=1.4.118.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)". Which is understandable, since SQLite-net dll
>   in bin folder is different (it even has different version).

What I would want to do is to use PCL dll in my UWP app at this point, is there a way to force it? Any other ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filed this issue on [Github](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/601#issuecomment-321998090)

Should be resolved in [1.5.166-beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.5.166-beta)