# Xamarin Forms UWP Sqlite connection, Could not load file or assembly SQLite-net

Tags: sqlite, uwp, xamarin.forms

I am stuck in connecting sqlite with xamarin forms/pcl/uwp application. Following is my code to set path for database

**Android** (Following works perfectly alright)

```
App1.globals.path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
//App1.globals.path=> /data/user/0/com.companyname.App1/files
LoadApplication(new App1.App());
```

**UWP** (Following does not work)

```
App1.globals.path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
//App1.globals.path => C:\Users\sami.akram\AppData\Local\Packages\8e3de984-9360-4549-a5cc-80071995402b_hy7qfqqm9rwga\LocalState
LoadApplication(new App1.App());
```

Following is the code in **App1 (Portable)** => Main App

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace App1
{

    public class globals
    {
        public static string path = "test.db3";
    }

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(globals.path, "test.db3");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            SetMainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Error I face is

> Could not load file or assembly 'SQLite-net, Version=1.4.118.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

[image]

But assembly version should not be any issue as I have installed same sqllite for all projects following image shows it. Note I tried the app with .net 4.5 and .net 4.6 but it results same.

[image]

I tried clean solution rebuild solution. Nothing is helping yet, same error could not load assembly..

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497992/pcl-vs-net-standard-library-for-sqlite-in-uwp) for details

Answer (score 3):

You might also need to ensure you have the VS extension provided by Sqlite.org installed.

Basically, you need to enable SQLite on UWP Apps. The SQLite core engine is already included on iOS and Android, but not on Windows. Therefore, you wil need to install the SQLite extension for Visual Studio, which provides precompiled binaries for the database engine and automates the task of including the required files with new projects.

A detailed article with steps on how to integrate Sqlite package in Xamarin.Forms project for UWP can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx)

Comment: thank you sir. forgot to add this to my project again when i purchased vs enterprise.

Comment: That extension says it is not compatible with my version of VS (16.4.4). It further says it might cause VS to become unstable.

Answer (score 3):

There's an issue with the "sqlite-net-pcl" NuGet package version **1.4.118.0** that only affects UWP projects referencing a Xamarin.Forms **PCL** project.
The bug has been fixed with the "sqlite-net-pcl" version 1.5.166-beta.

A couple of issues have been added to the official SQLite-net GitHub page:

- [Could not load SQLite-net on Xamarin.Forms UWP #627](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/627)
- [Version numbers in netstandard1.1 and portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10 #601](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/601)

Comment: You also have to update the package in the PCL (not only UWP). Otherwise you get `System.MissingMethodException` for `CreateTableAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use platform-specific **Windows.Storage** API to determine the database file path. You can use following link for help

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/#Windows_10_Universal_Windows_Platform_UWP

Here is the sample code:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Todo/

Comment: Sorry dear i edited my question. When used `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` it still gives same exception

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. The problem is that you have no permission to access windows local folder in portable library with `Version=4.0.10.0`  `System.IO`.

**portable library System.IO version**

[image: portable library System.IO version]
**UWP client project System.IO version**

[image: UWP client project System.IO version]

The way to use sqlite within xamarin form depends on dependency service. you could refer to the following.

```
public interface IFileHelper
{
  string GetLocalFilePath(string filename);
}
```

**Interface implementation**

```
using Windows.Storage;
...

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileHelper))]
namespace Todo.UWP
{
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
    {
        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

**usage**

```
var path = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("TodoSQLite.db3")
var db = new SQLiteConnection(path);
```

For more please refer to [Local Databases](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a particular issue of sqlite-net.
Even with the implementation of xamarin's page ([See xamarin's implementation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/#Windows_10_Universal_Windows_Platform_UWP)) it shows that error.

What worked for me was to update the sqlite-net-pcl to 1.5.166-beta.